# Getting error in console Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known property of 'div' in angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template, ecmascript-5

After calling ngif statement for edit state i get this error in console
***Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known property of 'div'***
I must mention that my first condition works well and that i have imported BrowserModule and CommonModule to app.module.ts

This is my tasks.component.html

```
<div class="container mt-5">
<div *ngIf ="tasks?.length > 0; else noTasks" >
    <ul class="list-group" >
        <li *ngFor = "let task of tasks" class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <strong> {{task.title}}: </strong> {{task.description}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-auto">
                    <button (click)="editTask($event, task)" class="btn btn-link"> Edit </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-auto">
                    <button (click)="deleteTask($event, task)" class="btn btn-link"> Delete </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div *ngif="editState && taskToEdit.id == task.id">
                <form (ngSubmit)="udpateTask(task)">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Task title</label>
                                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="task.title" name="title" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Task Description</label>
                                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="task.description" name="description" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Update Task">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>

<ng-template #noTasks>
    <h5>There are no tasks to list</h5>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: `*ngif` not same as `*ngIf`

Answer (score 1):

This line *ngif="editState && taskToEdit.id == task.id" contains a typo, and should read *ngIf. Please check.